How do I notify observers when my value is updated?
I am trying to modify some data from API. I have successfully implemented callbacks inside a nested recyclerview. But my selector doesn't work now. Why is that and how do I fix it?
Below are the adapter classes.
Survey Container Adapter
class SurveyContainerAdapter(
    private val surveyList: ArrayList<DataSurvey>,
    private val context: Context,
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SurveyContainerAdapter.SurveyContainerViewHolder>() {

    private var onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback? = null

    inner class SurveyContainerViewHolder(val binding: SurveyContainerLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(surveyData: DataSurvey, position: Int) {
            binding.tvSurveyTitle.text = "${surveyData.name} (${position + 1}/$itemCount)"
            binding.ivCloseSurvey.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickCallback?.onItemClicked(surveyData, position)
            }

            if (surveyData.assets.isNotEmpty()) {
                binding.ivCloseSurvey.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            binding.rvSurveyItem.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            val adapterItem = SurveyItemAdapter(surveyData.items)
            adapterItem.setOnValueCallback(object : SurveyItemAdapter.SurveyItemListener{
                override fun onValueChanged(surveyId: String, itemId: String, newValue: Any?) {
                    onItemClickCallback?.onValueClicked(surveyId, itemId, newValue)
                }
            })
            binding.rvSurveyItem.adapter = adapterItem
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SurveyContainerViewHolder {
        val view =
            SurveyContainerLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return SurveyContainerViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = surveyList.size

    interface OnItemClickCallback {
        fun onItemClicked(data: DataSurvey, position: Int)
        fun onValueClicked(surveyId: String, itemId: String, newValue: Any?)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickCallback(onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback) {
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SurveyContainerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(surveyList[position], position)
    }
}

Survey Item Adapter
package com.envisions.people.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.envisions.people.R
import com.envisions.people.api.responses.SurveyItem
import com.envisions.people.databinding.SurveyItemLayoutBinding


class SurveyItemAdapter(
    private val surveyItemList: List<SurveyItem>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SurveyItemAdapter.SurveyItemViewHolder>() {
        private var surveyItemListener : SurveyItemListener? = null
    inner class SurveyItemViewHolder(private val binding: SurveyItemLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(surveyData: SurveyItem, position: Int) {
            binding.tvSurveyItemTitle.text = "${position + 1}. ${surveyData.name}"

            if (position == itemCount - 1) {
                binding.surveyItemSeparator.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            binding.cbConfirmSurveyItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                if (isChecked) {
                    buttonView.isChecked = true
                    binding.cbCancelSurveyItem.isChecked = false
//                    binding.cbCancelSurveyItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_outline_cancel)
                } else {
                    buttonView.isChecked = false
                    binding.cbCancelSurveyItem.isChecked = true
//                    binding.cbCancelSurveyItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_outline_cancel_red)
                }

                surveyItemListener?.onValueChanged(surveyData.surveyId, surveyData.id, isChecked)
//                Log.e("value on cbConfirm", "value : ${surveyData.valueItem}")
//                Log.e("value survey Item id", "value : ${surveyData.surveyId}")
//                Log.e("value survey id", "value : ${surveyData.id}")
            }

            binding.cbCancelSurveyItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                if (isChecked) {
                    buttonView.isChecked = true
                    binding.cbConfirmSurveyItem.isChecked = false

                } else {
                    buttonView.isChecked = false
                    binding.cbConfirmSurveyItem.isChecked = true

                }

                surveyItemListener?.onValueChanged(surveyData.surveyId, surveyData.id, !isChecked)
//
//                Log.e("value on cbCancel", "value : ${surveyData.valueItem}")
//                Log.e("value survey Item id", "value : ${surveyData.surveyId}")
//                Log.e("value survey id", "value : ${surveyData.id}")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SurveyItemViewHolder {
        val view =
            SurveyItemLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return SurveyItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = surveyItemList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SurveyItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(surveyItemList[position], position)
    }

    fun setOnValueCallback(onValueClickCallback: SurveyItemListener) {
        this.surveyItemListener = onValueClickCallback
    }

    interface SurveyItemListener {
        fun onValueChanged(surveyId: String, itemId: String, newValue: Any?)
    }
}

While below is my view model class.
package com.envisions.people.viewmodels

import android.location.Location
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.envisions.people.api.responses.DataArea
import com.envisions.people.api.responses.DataAssetItem
import com.envisions.people.api.responses.DataLocationItem
import com.envisions.people.api.responses.DataSurvey
import com.envisions.people.data.models.ResultState
import com.envisions.people.data.repository.AreaRepository
import com.envisions.people.data.repository.AssetRepository
import com.envisions.people.data.repository.InspectionRepository
import com.envisions.people.data.repository.LocationRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.File

class CheckInViewModel(
    private val locationRepository: LocationRepository?,
    private val inspectionRepository: InspectionRepository?,
    private val areaRepository: AreaRepository?,
    private val assetRepository: AssetRepository?
) : ViewModel() {

    var nearestLocation: DataLocationItem? = null

    private val _isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean> = _isLoading

    private var _error = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var errorResponse: LiveData<String> = _error

    val surveyItem = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<DataSurvey>>()

    private val _areaList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<DataArea?>?>()
    val areaList: LiveData<ArrayList<DataArea?>?> = _areaList

    private val _assetList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<DataAssetItem>>()
    val assetList: LiveData<ArrayList<DataAssetItem>> = _assetList

    val allAssetsLoaded = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    // LiveData for etCheckInNotes
    val etCheckInNotesLiveData: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    // Combined LiveData for etCheckInNotes and surveyItem
    val combinedLiveData: MediatorLiveData<CheckInData> = MediatorLiveData()

    init {
        combinedLiveData.addSource(surveyItem) { surveyItem ->
            val checkInData = CheckInData(etCheckInNotesLiveData.value, surveyItem)
            combinedLiveData.value = checkInData
        }

        combinedLiveData.addSource(etCheckInNotesLiveData) { notes ->
            val checkInData = CheckInData(notes, surveyItem.value ?: arrayListOf())
            combinedLiveData.value = checkInData
        }
    }


    data class CheckInData(val notes: String?, val surveyItems: ArrayList<DataSurvey>)

    fun setLocationViewModel(token: String, currentLat: Double, currentLon: Double) {
        allAssetsLoaded.value = false

        Log.e("CheckInViewModel", "latitude : $currentLat")
        Log.e("CheckInViewModel", "latitude : $currentLon")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            locationRepository?.setLocation(token)
                ?.collect { result ->
                    when (result) {
                        is ResultState.Loading -> {
                            // Handle loading state, e.g., show a progress indicator
                            _isLoading.value = true
                        }

                        is ResultState.Success -> {
                            val locationDataList = result.data.data.toList()
                            // Access specific location data from locationResponse object
                            Log.e("CheckInViewModel", locationDataList.toString())
                            val nearestLocationCheck =
                                calculateNearestDistance(locationDataList, currentLat, currentLon)
                            Log.e(
                                "CheckInViewModel",
                                "Nearest Location : ${nearestLocationCheck.toString()}"
                            )

                            nearestLocation = nearestLocationCheck
                            getArea(token, nearestLocation?.id.orEmpty())
                        }

                        is ResultState.Error -> {
                            // Handle error, e.g., show Toast or navigate to error screen
//                            makeToast(context, result.error)
                            _isLoading.value = false
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    fun getArea(token: String, locationId: String) {
        var completedAssetCalls = 0
        viewModelScope.launch {
            areaRepository?.getArea(token, locationId)?.collect { result ->
                when (result) {
                    is ResultState.Loading -> {
                        // Handle loading state, e.g., show a progress indicator
                        _isLoading.value = true
                    }

                    is ResultState.Success -> {
                        val currentAreaList = _areaList.value
                            ?: arrayListOf() // Get the current value or create an empty list if null
                        currentAreaList.addAll(
                            result.data.data ?: emptyList()
                        ) // Add the new elements
                        _areaList.value =
                            currentAreaList // Update the MutableLiveData with the new list


//                        for (item in result.data.data ?: arrayListOf()) {
//                            Log.e(TAG, "result.data.data ${result.data.data}")
//                            _areaList.value?.add(item)
//                        }


                        for (area in _areaList.value ?: arrayListOf()) {
                            getAsset(token, area?.id.orEmpty(), object : FetchCallback {
                                override fun onDataLoaded() {
                                    completedAssetCalls++
                                    if (completedAssetCalls == _areaList.value?.size) {
                                        allAssetsLoaded.value = true
                                        _isLoading.postValue(false)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }

                    is ResultState.Error -> {
                        // Handle error, e.g., show Toast or navigate to error screen
//                            makeToast(context, result.error)
                        _error.postValue(result.error)
                        _isLoading.value = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getAsset(token: String, areaId: String, fetchCallback: FetchCallback) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            assetRepository?.getAsset(token, areaId)?.collect { result ->
                when (result) {
                    is ResultState.Loading -> {
                        // Handle loading state, e.g., show a progress indicator
                        _isLoading.value = true
                    }

                    is ResultState.Success -> {

                        val currentAssetList = _assetList.value
                            ?: arrayListOf() // Get the current value or create an empty list if null
                        currentAssetList.addAll(
                            result.data.data ?: emptyList()
                        ) // Add the new elements
                        _assetList.value =
                            currentAssetList // Update the MutableLiveData with the new list
//
//                        for (item in result.data.data?: arrayListOf()) {
//                            _assetList.value?.add(item)
//                        }

                        fetchCallback.onDataLoaded()
                    }

                    is ResultState.Error -> {
                        // Handle error, e.g., show Toast or navigate to error screen
//                            makeToast(context, result.error)
                        _error.postValue(result.error)
                        _isLoading.value = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun calculateNearestDistance(
        listLocation: List<DataLocationItem>?,
        currentLat: Double,
        currentLon: Double
    ): DataLocationItem? {
        var nearestLocationItem: DataLocationItem? = null
        var nearestDistance = Float.MAX_VALUE

        for (itemLocation in listLocation ?: arrayListOf()) {
            val result = FloatArray(1)
            val (latitudeStr, longitudeStr) = itemLocation.coordinate.split(", ")
            Location.distanceBetween(
                currentLat,
                currentLon,
                latitudeStr.toDouble(),
                longitudeStr.toDouble(),
                result
            )
            val distance = result[0]
            Log.e("CheckInViewModel", "Distance :  ${distance.toInt()}, Item : $itemLocation")
            if (distance < nearestDistance) {
                nearestDistance = distance
                nearestLocationItem = itemLocation
            }
        }

        Log.e(
            "CheckInViewModel",
            "Nearest Distance :  ${nearestDistance.toInt()}, Nearest Item : $nearestLocationItem"
        )

        if (nearestDistance.toInt() > (nearestLocationItem?.radius?.toInt()
                ?: 500)
        ) nearestLocationItem = null

        return nearestLocationItem
    }

    fun postCheckIn(
        token: String,
        notes: String,
        locationId: String,
        assetId: ArrayList<DataAssetItem>,
        fileList: ArrayList<File>,
        surveyList: ArrayList<DataSurvey>
    ) =
        inspectionRepository?.postInspection(
            token,
            notes,
            locationId,
            assetId,
            fileList,
            surveyList
        )

    fun getSurveyGeneral(token: String) {
        _isLoading.postValue(true)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            inspectionRepository?.getSurvey(token, null)?.collect { result ->
                when (result) {
                    is ResultState.Error ->
                        _error.postValue(result.error)

                    ResultState.Loading -> _isLoading.postValue(true)
                    is ResultState.Success -> {
                        _isLoading.postValue(false)
//                        _surveyItem.postValue(result.data)

                        val listSurvey = result.data.data.filter { dataSurvey ->
                            dataSurvey.items.any { surveyItem -> surveyItem.type.name == "checklist" }
                        }

                        surveyItem.postValue(listSurvey as ArrayList<DataSurvey>?)
                        val arrayTest = ArrayList<Any?>()
                        surveyItem.value?.forEach { data ->
                            data.items.forEach { item ->
                                Log.e(TAG, "item: $item")
                                arrayTest.add(item.valueItem)
                                Log.e(TAG, "arraytest : $arrayTest")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getSurveyAsset(token: String, assetId: String) {
        _isLoading.postValue(true)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            inspectionRepository?.getSurvey(token, assetId)?.collect { result ->
                when (result) {
                    is ResultState.Error ->
                        _error.postValue(result.error)

                    ResultState.Loading -> _isLoading.postValue(true)
                    is ResultState.Success -> {
                        _isLoading.postValue(false)
//                        _surveyItem.postValue(result.data)

                        val listSurvey = result.data.data.filter { dataSurvey ->
                            dataSurvey.items.any { surveyItem -> surveyItem.type.name == "checklist" }
                        } as ArrayList<DataSurvey>

                        val updatedList = ArrayList<DataSurvey>()

                        surveyItem.value?.forEach { dataSurvey ->
                            updatedList.add(dataSurvey)
                        }

                        // Now, iterate through listSurvey and add elements with unique names
                        listSurvey.forEach { newSurveyGet ->
                            val isNew =
                                updatedList.none { existingSurvey -> existingSurvey.name == newSurveyGet.name }
                            if (isNew) {
                                updatedList.add(newSurveyGet)
                            }
                        }

                        surveyItem.postValue(updatedList)
                        Log.e(TAG, "surveyItem = ${surveyItem.value}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun updateSurveyItemValueItem(surveyId: String, itemId: String, newValue: Any?) {
        val updatedList = surveyItem.value?.map { survey ->
            if (survey.id == surveyId) {
                survey.copy(
                    items = survey.items.map { item ->
                        if (item.id == itemId) {
                            item.copy(valueItem = newValue)
                        } else {
                            item
                        }
                    }
                )
            } else {
                survey
            }
        }?.toMutableList()

        updatedList?.let { surveyItem.value = it as ArrayList<DataSurvey> }
    }

    interface FetchCallback {
        fun onDataLoaded()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CHECKINVIEWMODEL"
    }

}

And finally this is my implementation in the activity class.
checkInViewModel.surveyItem.observe(this) { surveyData ->
            if (surveyData.isNotEmpty()) {
                surveyAdapter = SurveyContainerAdapter(checkInViewModel.surveyItem.value ?: arrayListOf(), this)
                binding.rvSurveyInspection.layoutManager =
                    LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
                binding.rvSurveyInspection.adapter = surveyAdapter

                surveyAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object :
                    SurveyContainerAdapter.OnItemClickCallback {
                    override fun onItemClicked(data: DataSurvey, position: Int) {
                        if (position != -1) {
                            updateSurvey(position)
                        }

                        val foundAsset : ArrayList<DataAssetItem> = arrayListOf()

                        assetList.forEachIndexed { _, dataAssetItem ->
                            data.assets.forEach { assetsItem ->
                                if(assetsItem.assetId == dataAssetItem.id){
                                    foundAsset.add(dataAssetItem)
                                    return@forEachIndexed
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if(foundAsset.isNotEmpty()){
                            foundAsset.forEach { assetItem ->
                                val foundAssetIndex = assetList.indexOf(assetItem)
                                assetList.removeAt(foundAssetIndex)
                                assetAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(foundAssetIndex)
                                assetAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(
                                    foundAssetIndex,
                                    assetList.size.minus(foundAssetIndex)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onValueClicked(surveyId: String, itemId: String, newValue: Any?) {
                        checkInViewModel.updateSurveyItemValueItem(surveyId, itemId, newValue)
                    }
                })
            }

            surveyData.forEach { dataSurvey ->
                Log.e(TAG, "test $dataSurvey")
            }
        }

UPDATE
I have written the xml file below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSurveyItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        tools:text="1. Test"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvAddSurveyImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/checklistContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:gravity = "start|center"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/checklistContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvSurveyItemTitle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvAddSurveyImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbConfirmSurveyItem"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_survey_enable"
            android:button="@null"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbCancelSurveyItem"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_survey_disable"
            android:button="@null"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddSurveyImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add images"
        android:textColor="@color/people_color"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvSurveyItemTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvSurveyItemTitle" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvImageSurvey"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAddSurveyImage"
        tools:itemCount="1"
        tools:listitem="@layout/check_in_image_layout" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/surveyItemSeparator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_content_blur"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvImageSurvey"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

While below is my selector_survey_disable or maybe enable because they're similar
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_outline_cancel"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_outline_cancel_red"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_outline_cancel"/>
</selector>


Which selector doesn't work exactly? Can you provide a bit more detail? Some of the code you added is commented out.

Yes be specific and try to add images for reference.

I have updated the question with selectors. So I am trying to use some data from an API. Those data is sent to the surveyContainerAdapter. Now, I am trying to observe valueItem inside the SurveyItem class that is wrapped in a class called DataSurvey. I have implemented callbacks to get the edited valueItems. But now the checkboxes won't use the selector anymore.

Please don't mind the commented code because that was me testing something
